# Another Sort with multiple criterion

Tags: sorting

I have a list

```
list={{ω->0.538826+1.31221 I},{ω->-0.538826+1.31221 I},{ω->-1.2444-0.68023 I},{ω->1.2444-0.68023 I},{ω->0.496864+1.32811 I},{ω->-0.496864+1.32811 I},{ω->1.22187-0.719147 I},{ω->-1.22187-0.719147 I},{ω->0.454442+1.34261 I},{ω->-0.454442+1.34261 I},{ω->1.19811-0.757303 I},{ω->-1.19811-0.757303 I},{ω->1.17316-0.794657 I},{ω->-1.17316-0.794657 I},{ω->0.411617+1.35568 I},{ω->-0.411617+1.35568 I},{ω->-1.14704-0.831174 I},{ω->1.14704-0.831174 I}}
```

and I would like to sort it by ascending positive. I tried with the Sort command

```
Sort[list, (Re[#1[[1, 2]]] < Re[#2[[1, 2]]] && Re[#1[[1, 2]]] > 0) &]
```

but it does not sort them in desired order:

```
{{ω->1.14704-0.831174 I},{ω->-1.14704-0.831174 I},{ω->-0.411617+1.35568 I},{ω->0.411617+1.35568 I},{ω->-1.17316-0.794657 I},{ω->1.17316-0.794657 I},{ω->-1.19811-0.757303 I},{ω->1.19811-0.757303 I},{ω->-0.454442+1.34261 I},{ω->0.454442+1.34261 I},{ω->-1.22187-0.719147 I},{ω->1.22187-0.719147 I},{ω->-0.496864+1.32811 I},{ω->0.496864+1.32811 I},{ω->1.2444-0.68023 I},{ω->-1.2444-0.68023 I},{ω->-0.538826+1.31221 I},{ω->0.538826+1.31221 I}}
```

How am I wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In which sense " it does not function" ?

Comment: The `&& Re[#1[[1, 2]]] > 0` part makes this not be a "valid" ordering i.e. the outcome will depend on the initial order of the list (and sorting algorithm used).

Comment: @ssch, how can I overcome the problem?

Comment: Can you clarify on the ordering? `SortBy[list, -Abs[Re[ω /. #]] &]` doesn't match your desired output

Comment: @ssch, I would like to have the terms with the smallest positive real part first. the answer of Jacob Akkerboom solved my problem. Do you suggest any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about first selecting the values that you want to keep and then sorting? For example

```
limitedList2 = Select[list, Re[#[[1, 2]]] > 0 &];
SortBy[limitedList2, Re[#[[1, 2]]] &]
```

> {{ω->0.411617 +1.35568 I},{ω->0.454442 +1.34261 I},{ω->0.496864 +1.32811 I},{ω->0.538826 +1.31221 I},{ω->1.14704 -0.831174 I},{ω->1.17316 -0.794657 I},{ω->1.19811 -0.757303 I},{ω->1.22187 -0.719147 I},{ω->1.2444 -0.68023 I}}

or if you want a more compact data structure

```
limitedList = 
 Cases[list, _Complex?(Composition[Positive, Re]), Infinity];
SortBy[limitedList, Re]
```

> {0.411617 + 1.35568 I, 0.454442 + 1.34261 I, 0.496864 + 1.32811 I, 
>    0.538826 + 1.31221 I, 1.14704 - 0.831174 I, 1.17316 - 0.794657 I, 
>    1.19811 - 0.757303 I, 1.22187 - 0.719147 I, 1.2444 - 0.68023 I}

Comment: thank you very much, it works perfectly.